# Google Analytics AMP Data Sources & Source/Medium confusion

Tags: google-analytics

One of our clients has AMP templates set up for their Ecommerce site. They're capturing AMP & non-AMP data in the same GA property. When they're looking in GA and trying to filter for AMP traffic, there's been a bit of confusion.

There were two different ways that they were filtering for AMP traffic:

1. By looking at the Source/Medium, and manually selecting all Source/Mediums that had AMP contained in them ie: client-amp--mobify-com.cdn.ampproject.org / referral
2. By setting up a new segment that filtered for all sessions which contained AMP as a Data Source.

These two different ways however were giving vastly differing data.

I then noticed when looking through all the listed Sources/Mediums that there was actually an identical pair for client-amp--mobify-com.cdn.ampproject.org / referral, except one had a data source set as AMP and the other had a data source set as Web.

I'm confused here, as it seems like the data source for that should've been set to AMP and that there would only be one of those Source/Mediums as its very clearly coming from an AMP source.

Why is there a pair of identical Source/Mediums that have differing data sources when it's clearly an AMP data source?